# Changing a text label into an image

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, labels

I want to change a text label to an image. This label is on WooCommerce shop page.

[image: Member Discount]

The script contains the text "Member discount!":

```
$label = __( 'Member discount!', 'woocommerce-memberships' );
```

I tried changing the script, E.g.: `<img src="http://siteh87h8.com/gambar.png" />`, but the text is still not changed.

Relevant code:

```
/**
 * Get member discount badge
 *
 * @since 1.6.4
 * @param \WC_Product $product The product object to output a badge for (passed to filter)
 * @param bool $variation Whether to output a discount badge specific for a product variation (default false)
 * @return string
 */
public function get_member_discount_badge( $product, $variation = false ) {

      $label = __( 'Member discount!', 'woocommerce-memberships' );
    // we have a slight different output for badge classes and filter
    if ( true !== $variation ) {
        global $post;

        // used in filter for backwards compatibility reasons
        $the_post = $post;

        if ( ! $the_post instanceof WP_Post ) {
            $the_post = $product->post;
        }

        $badge = '<span class="onsale wc-memberships-member-discount">' . esc_html( $label ) . '</span>';

        /**
         * Filter the member discount badge
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         * @param string $badge The badge HTML
         * @param \WP_Post $post The product post object
         * @param \WC_Product_Variation $variation The product variation
         */
        $badge = apply_filters( 'wc_memberships_member_discount_badge', $badge, $the_post, $product );

    } else {

        $badge = '<span class="wc-memberships-variation-member-discount">' . esc_html( $label ) . '</span>';

        /**
         * Filter the variation member discount badge
         *
         * @since 1.3.2
         * @param string $badge The badge HTML
         * @param \WC_Product|\WC_Product_Variation $variation The product variation
         */
        $badge = apply_filters( 'wc_memberships_variation_member_discount_badge', $badge, $product );

    }

    return $badge;
}


/**
 * Filter the member discount badge for products excluded
 * from member discount rules
 *
 * @internal
 *
 * @since 1.7.0
 * @param string $badge Badge HTML
 * @param \WP_Post $post The post object
 * @param \WC_Product $product The product object
 * @return string Empty string if product is excluded from member discounts
 */
public function disable_discount_badge_for_excluded_products( $badge, $post, $product ) {
    return $this->is_product_excluded_from_member_discounts( $product ) ? '' : $badge;
}
```

Full script here: http://pastebin.com/AGztQYYt (relevant code starts on line 1032).

**Edit:** The accepted answer worked for me. Along with the code from that answer, I used this CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products.grid li.product .badgescarisan{position:absolute;right: 0px;}
```

And this HTML:

```
$badge = '<span class="badgescarisan wc-memberships-member-discount">' .
                        '<img src="https://www.conecplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Badges-Membership-Carisan.png" alt="meow">' .
                '</span>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changing the label text (text only)

The text "Member discount!" can be changed using a translation filter, but it's not possible to add an image or any HTML to that because it is escaped later in the code referenced in the question:

```
 $badge = '<span class="onsale wc-memberships-member-discount">' . esc_html( $label ) . '</span>';
```

Here is an example showing how to change the *Member discount!* text, but it will only work with text, not HTML:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse244685_change_text', 20, 3 );
function wpse244685_change_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce-memberships' !== $domain ) {
        return $translated_text;        
    }

    // make the changes to the text
    switch( $untranslated_text ) {

            case 'Member discount!' :
                // $translated_text = __( 'New text', 'text_domain' ); // Example of new string
                $translated_text = ''; // Empty strings should not be translated
            break;

            // add more items
     }

    return $translated_text;        
}
```

### Adding an image or other HTML

Depending on how your product is configured, it looks like you can change the HTML for the badge, and therefore add an image, via either the `wc_memberships_member_discount_badge` or `wc_memberships_variation_member_discount_badge` filters as follows:

**Standard Product:**

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_member_discount_badge', 'wpse244685_wc_memberships_member_discount_badge', 10, 3 );
function wpse244685_wc_memberships_member_discount_badge( $badge, $the_post, $product ) {
    $badge = '<span class="onsale wc-memberships-member-discount">' . 
                            '<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="meow">' .
                     '</span>';

    return $badge;      
}
```

**Variable Product:**

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_variation_member_discount_badge', 'wpse244685_wc_memberships_variation_member_discount_badge', 10, 2 );
function wpse244685_wc_memberships_member_discount_badge( $badge, $product ) {
    $badge = '<span class="onsale wc-memberships-member-discount">' . 
                            '<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="meow">' .
                     '</span>';

    return $badge;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Succeed ^o^ I change the css class "onsale" to "badgescarisan"

```
.woocommerce ul.products.grid li.product .badgescarisan{position:absolute;right: 0px;}
```

And add pictures

```
$badge = '<span class="badgescarisan wc-memberships-member-discount">' . '<img src="https://www.conecplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Badges-Membership-Carisan.png" alt="meow">' .'</span>';
```

Thank you for helping me. Sorry my english is bad. ^_^

Comment: Glad to help, Rangga! I understood what you were going for :-) Also, while this additional content you've posted may be helpful, it should be added to your original question and not an answer. I went ahead and took care of that. Please delete this answer. Oh, and welcome to WPSE!

Comment: Haha.. I'm Sorry and thank your revision.
I'm Newbie Using Stackexchange :D